# Users cannot access web site hosted on IIS, configured with Windows Authentication ON

Tags: security, iis, windows-authentication, user-accounts

I’m currently developing a web site that uses windows authentication, with ApplicationPoolIdentity configured with Identity=Application Pool. I can connect by login with my administrator user when asked by the browser and it works perfect, but if any other user tries to access, the browser asks for the credentials 3 times and then it throws a 401 Error.

Test scenarios:

1. If the server is configured with Anonymous Authentication ON, everybody is able to open the page.
2. If I try to set the application pool Identity to a regular user account, IIS doesn’t recognize the user/password provided.
3. The folder C:\inetpub\ was set with full control to Everyone, but the users can’t connect anyway.
4. The folder C:\inetpub\ was set with full control to a specific user, but the user can’t connect anyway.
5. Following a recommendation from another post, the following section was added to the web.config :

```
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

The windows logs in the Event Viewer don’t store anything about a failed login.

thanks for your comments

**Update**

i enabled and add Failed Request Tracing Rules to web site

it was result

> ModuleName :IIS Web Core
>
> Notification : AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST
>
> HttpStatus : 401
>
> HttpReason : Unauthorized
>
> ErrorCode : Access is denied (0x80070005)

i searched this error but the post tell me, maybe permissions, but i set everyone as full control and it doesn't working

Comment: Are you sure that user and password are correct?

Comment: Yes Mr Martin, i confirmed this

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Check IIS log files first to see what is the sub status.

Comment: is this logs stored in %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles ?

Comment: I updated the questions with information from logs  @LexLi

Comment: What's happening is Kerberos auth is failing.  Look closely at the web site URL.  It should look something like http://myintranetsite.local.  The run this command:  *setspn -Q HTTP/myintranetsite.local*.  Does it return any duplicates?  If so, get rid of the duplicate which is not in use.